# WCF REST service, IIS and Database

Tags: wcf, sql-server-2008, rest, iis

I have a problem with a WCF REST service which I can't understand.
The thing is that the service is hosted with IIS.

In the service I have two functions:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFishMapService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
                BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
                ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                UriTemplate = "/FindAllRecords")]
     List<Record> findAllRecords();


    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
                BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
                ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                UriTemplate = "/returnHello")]
      String returnHello();
}
```

The second one is just a simple test function that returns a string.
The first one returns a List and connects to a database on my machine made by MS SQL Server 2008.

So... what is going on while testing:
- if I test the second function with my IP address like this:

```
ipAddress/MyApp/FishMapService.svc/returnHello
```

Everything si ok!

- if I do the same with the second function but with localhost:

  localhost:57640/FishMapService.svc/returnHello

Everything is also ok! Get a nice and beautiful responce!

- if i test the first one with localhost:

  localhost:57640/FishMapService.svc/FindAllRecords

I see the result of the query that has been sent! Beautiful again! I see all the
information I need.

- if I test the same one but with my IP:

  ipAddress/MyApp/FishMapService.svc/FindAllRecords

Get this in the browser "[]" ?!

Why is this happening?! Any ideas?

Comment: Is it just case sensitive?

Comment: I'm sorry this was my mistake. While writing the post. It's edited now.

Comment: Does someone have any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved!

The solution was in the permisions for the current database in MS SQL Studio. A good advice is to check the log files for the server. You can do this by Management (folder) -> SQL Server Logs -> Current Log

In the new window you will who is trying to log into your SQL Server. For me the it was "IIS APPPOOL\Default Website". So you go to the database table [DataBaseTableNae] -> Security -> Right Click on "Users" -> New User

Then add the new user with the name you've already saw in the log file, again for me it was "IIS APPPOOL\Default Website" and give this user the permissions you want.

At the end you should be able to see a responce be typeing in your browser ipAddress/MyApp/FishMapService.svc/FindAllRecords (that's the url in my project)

Hope this will be useful for someone!

Cheers!